# How to refer to a glyph in a font from xelatex?

Tags: xetex

I have a font, and I want to refer to a specific glyph without any regards to the encoding (I am using Unicode for everything else). Just pick glyph #n out of it. Can this be done in xelatex?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To insert a specific glyph when the glyph index is known, you can use the `\XeTeXglyph` primitive:

```
\XeTeXglyph 123 % inserts glyph with number 123
```

Comment: I get no text after inserting a glyph. Is this a limitation or?